# To find FM signal's phase in Matlab

Tags: matlab, telecommunication, phase, modulation

I want to find the phase of an FM signal. Matlab code of message signal is

```
m= ones(1,Fs); 
m= [m(1:round(.4*Fs))*1, m(round(.4*Fs)+1:round(.7*Fs))*-2 ...
    m(round(.7*Fs)+1:Fs)*0];
```

How can I find phase of FM signal?

Comment: It is obvious if you understand what FM is. What have you tried? You need to define a modulation index, by the way

Comment: function ELE361_Proje2(Kf,Fc,Fs)
Kf=50;
Fc=400;
Fs=100;
t=linspace(0,1,Fs);
m= ones(1,Fs); 
m= [m(1:round(.4*Fs))*1 m(round(.4*Fs)+1:round(.7*Fs))*-2 m(round(.7*Fs)+1:Fs)*0];%message signal
fi_t =2*pi*Kf*trapz(m,t);%phase
u=10*cos(2*pi*Fc*t+fi_t);%modulated signal
plot(t,m);

Comment: I tried trapz method to integrate but  I have obtained this graphiç(modulated signal: http://prntscr.com/23h6d2

Comment: See my answer. Next time you should update your queston to include code, because in a comment it can't be formatted properly

Answer (score 0):

You need the following corrections in your code:

```
Kf=50; %%% increase Kf no notice effect
Fc=400;
Fs=5000; %%% Increase Fs. Nyquist criterion!
t=linspace(0,1,Fs);
m= ones(1,Fs);
m= [m(1:round(.4*Fs))*1 m(round(.4*Fs)+1:round(.7*Fs))*-2 m(round(.7*Fs)+1:Fs)*0];
fi_t =2*pi*Kf*cumtrapz(t,m);%%% use cumtrapz, not cum. Reverse order
u=10*cos(2*pi*Fc*t+fi_t);
plot(t,u);
```